# i have a nested list json file and i am using json_normalize to have the data but i am facing TypeError

Tags: python, json, nested-lists, json-normalize

i have a dataset of 3 objects, i am intrested of the data in object 1 which has, but it have nested lists, the file looks like this :

```
[{'ob1': [{'values':{'ID':2133 ,'STATUS': closed,'name':'Sara'}}
          {'values':{'ID':5432,'STATUS': closed,'name':'Jon'}}
          {'values':{'ID':5442,'STATUS': closed,'name':'jen'}}}]
```

I want to expand the data and have a table of ID , STATUS, name.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df=pd.read_json('Data.json', lines=True)

df_values = pd.json_normalize(df , 
    record_path=['ob1','values'], 
    meta=[['ID', 'STATUS','name',]],errors='ignore')
```

the output give an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

in this line :

```
meta=[['ID', 'STATUS','name',]], errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score -1):

The JSON provided to the application isn't valid JSON it should look like:

```
[{"ob1":[{"values":{"ID":2133,"STATUS":"closed","name":"Sara"}},{"values":{"ID":5432,"STATUS":"closed","name":"Jon"}},{"values":{"ID":5442,"STATUS":"closed","name":"Jen"}}]}]
```

Or like:

```
[
  {
    "ob1": [
      {
        "values": {
          "ID": 2133,
          "STATUS": "closed",
          "name": "Sara"
        }
      },
      {
        "values": {
          "ID": 5432,
          "STATUS": "closed",
          "name": "Jon"
        }
      },
      {
        "values": {
          "ID": 5442,
          "STATUS": "closed",
          "name": "Jen"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thak you for your answer, the json that i have is valid and it extracted from a system we have, the data that i put is just an exsample and it is not valid, put it is still give me the same error that i provieded in the post, can you help me with that?